# jCheckbox list and check text value with another string array

Tags: java

In the app, I can export files and I am trying to create an import function as well. I do import the text files, but my issue is the following.

I have several checkboxes. See the image bellow. When I am exporting the file, I create a `.txt` that includes all the brands selected.

When I import the `.txt`, I can of course create an arraylist with all the values. I want to cross-check that list against all the checkboxes and "check" the boxes. For example, I have "avene" inside my list, and I want the "avene" checkbox (or ck01) to be checked. But I am unsure on how to proceed.

[image]

This is the way I am importing the file and creating an array:

```
BufferedReader bf1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(importpath + "\\additional_info\\brands.txt"));
String line1 = bf1.readLine();
selectedBrands = new ArrayList();
while(line1 != null) {
    line1 = bf.readLine();
    selectedBrands.add(line1);
}
```

And this is that I started trying to do. I tried a few things, like creating checkbox array, an object jlist that includes the checkboxes. I even tried creating a new jcheckbox list, but I am always getting an error:

`cannot find symbol` on the `.getText()` command.

I am adding the latest test I did with the `Object[]` list, but I have tried several other ways.

```
List<Checkbox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<Checkbox>();
Object[] newList = {ck01, ck02, ck03, ck04, ck05, ck06, ck07, ck08, ck09, ck10, ck11, ck12, ck13, ck14, ck15, ck16, ck17, ck18, ck19, ck20, ck21, ck22, ck23, ck24, ck25, ck26, ck27, ck28, ck29, ck30, ck31, ck32, ck33, ck34, ck35, ck36, ck37, ck38, ck39, ck40, ck41, ck42, ck43, ck44, ck45, ck46, ck47, ck48, ck49, ck50, ck51, ck52, ck53, ck54};

for (int i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {

    newList[i].getText();
}
```

***P.S. the app was created using NetBeans!

Comment: What are *"jlist"*? and *"jcheckbox"*? For instance, they are not in the code.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, this question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are two types of checkboxes. There's a `java.awt.Checkbox`, and a `javax.swing.JCheckBox`.

If you're using the `JCheckBox`, consider the following code.

If you're using the `Checkbox`, instead of `isSelected`, you would use `getState`, same with the setter.  And, instead of `getText`, you would use `getLabel`, as well as the setter method.

Keep in mind, this will be effective only if the text of each checkbox is unique.

In response to the use of an `Object` array, it will improve scalability if you use an array of the object, so in this case either a `JCheckBox[]` or a `Checkbox[]`.

Even better, use a mutable `List<JCheckBox>`.

Additionally, it's worth noting that Java will convert your path separators, so instead of un-escaping the `\`, you can just use a single `/`.

```
List<String> getSelected() {
    List<String> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    JCheckBox[] newList = { ck01, ck02, ck03, ck04, ck05, ck06, ck07, ck08, ck09, ck10, ck11, ck12, ck13, ck14, ck15, ck16, ck17, ck18, ck19, ck20, ck21, ck22, ck23, ck24, ck25, ck26, ck27, ck28, ck29, ck30,ck31, ck32, ck33, ck34, ck35, ck36, ck37, ck38, ck39, ck40,ck41, ck42, ck43, ck44, ck45, ck46, ck47, ck48, ck49, ck50,ck51, ck52, ck53, ck54 };
    for (JCheckBox checkbox : newList) {
        if (checkbox.isSelected())
            selected.add(checkbox.getText());
    }
    return selected;
}

void saveSelected() throws IOException {
    String path = importpath + "\\additional_info\\brands.txt";
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path)) {
        String newline = System.lineSeparator();
        for (String checkboxText : getSelected()) {
            writer.write(checkboxText);
            writer.write(newline);
        }
        writer.flush();
    }
}

void loadSelected() throws IOException {
    String path = importpath + "\\additional_info\\brands.txt";
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        JCheckBox[] checkboxes = { ck01, ck02, ck03, ck04, ck05, ck06, ck07, ck08, ck09, ck10, ck11, ck12, ck13, ck14, ck15, ck16, ck17, ck18, ck19, ck20, ck21, ck22, ck23, ck24, ck25, ck26, ck27, ck28, ck29, ck30,ck31, ck32, ck33, ck34, ck35, ck36, ck37, ck38, ck39, ck40,ck41, ck42, ck43, ck44, ck45, ck46, ck47, ck48, ck49, ck50,ck51, ck52, ck53, ck54 };
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            for (JCheckBox checkbox : checkboxes) {
                if (checkbox.getText().equals(line)) {
                    checkbox.setSelected(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working man thank you! It's the `void loadSelected()` that I had an issue with.